# Run application in test module with Maven

Tags: maven

I have a `TestingApplication` class in the test module which produces randomized automatized tests. It also can take arguments. How do I run this application with maven?

When I try to run it like this:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.domain.module.TestingApplication" -Dexec.args="arg0 arg1 arg2"
```

It throws `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`, because the class file is not in folder `target/classes` but `target/test/classes`.

Comment: Can you explain more in detail what you mean by `class in the test module which produces randomized automatized tests`? Why do you exec-maven-plugin?

Comment: I am sorry I don't know which information do you need to explain, it is just an application that is the test module (`src/test`) and I need it to run. I am using maven since it can help with dependencies and I just need to run it elsewhere by someone else and this way seems as the easiest option.

Comment: So you don't know why/and how and what `TestingApplication` is doing? It's not a test module...Tests are run by default via unit tests and not via an application which generates tests ..So first you should learn what this `TestingApplication` is doing and more important why it is doing ...and learn how to write unit and/or integration tests...

Comment: I exactly know what the application is doing but I don't know which info is relevant to you, since explaining every method will not help and will just lead to confusion. I just explain differently the same thing, I hope you get it this time :). I know what unit tests are but there is a way to test my application automatically with randomized tests so I made it, now I need to run it by someone else without worrying about dependencies.